# Kendo grid duplicate records inserted

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid in inline editing mode.
When I press "Add new item" button, new row is added and set to the edit mode.
By pressing the "Update" button multiple time, I'm able to insert duplicate records into database.

Is there a possibility to disable Update button after the first click?

Also row selection on kendo grid is lost after insert is performed.
Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Which version of KendoUI are you using? I cannot reproduce your problem with multiple-update. Can you share some code?

Comment: Yes, it is a normal behaviour loosing focus since the grid is redrawn.

Comment: I added trigger in the database table to prevent insertion of duplicate records.

Comment: It is not the latest version. It is v.2012.3.1315

Comment: Can you post some sample code for your grid and the controller action?

Answer (score 7):

This would happen if you don't return the ID of the newly inserted records. The Kendo DataSource would treat them as new unless you return the id values. More info is available in the [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.create).

Comment: Yes I'm doing that. I probably need to synchronize events, or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate records will get entered if you don't return the entire record with the ID of the newly created record.
**The important point being to return the "entire record", not just the "ID".**

```
public ContactBO CreateContact(ContactBO contact, int userid)
        {
            svc = new WCFService.VendorClient("BasicHttpBinding_IVendor", connectionString);
            contact.VendorReferenceID = userid;
            contact.ID = svc.SaveNewContact(contact, "external");
            return contact;
        }
```

Comment: Not quite sure why this originally had a downvote. I'm pretty sure that the format of data the datasource is expecting in response to the create is the same as format, i.e. the model schema. It might be the case that all that needs to be populated is the id property (whatever that might be called), but it's not enough just to return an "int" or similar from the server side.